# soundcards suddenly disappear (adafruit speaker bonnet + neo pixels)

Tags: raspbian-stretch, alsa

This afternoon I was playing sound through my adafruit speaker bonnet just fine.

That means I installed the [speakers](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-speaker-bonnet-for-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-usage) and [neopixels](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/python-usage) according to the guides and had multiple reboots for [circuit python](https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux), enabling [SPI](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-spi) etc.

Then this evening, after shutting down the pi, unplugging it, moving it to a new room of the house, and plugging it back in it, seems to have no idea what I'm talking about with respect to sound:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
--- no soundcards ---
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

What can have gone wrong and how can I put it back? What can I do to troubleshoot this?

### Update

I seem to have fixed the problem in a way that I don't understand.

I noticed this line at the end of my boot/config.txt (after the `dtoverlay=hifiberry-dac` line)

```
dtoverlay=spi1-3cs
```

I'm guessing this came from the `raspi-config` "enable SPI" process.

Commenting that out has fixed my problem! But why? This seems like a temporary fix since Circuit Python says it needs SPI and this probably killed it. It is not possible to have SPI enabled and use the DAC?

Comment: Try to reboot your Rpi. Once boot up completed, login to your Rpi and run a `dmesg`. The, post the output of `dmesg` here.

Comment: Wow, the output is huge. It won't fit here. Do you want me to grep for something specifically or just link to a gist?

Comment: Did you try to include the output in quotes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, that it would fit in a comment box if surrounded by "" or if you think it should be added to the question? Either way it seems better to use a gist: https://gist.github.com/KCErb/a8b1f5f4c9c3bb1ac0dd5169f3357931.

Comment: What you did is fix the issue. /boot/config.txt is the top level where these kind of interfaces are enabled and disabled and, if I'm not mistaken, the raspi-config menu does the commenting in and out. For some reason it was not doing so to you, and by doing it manually you fixed it.

Comment: But it seems possible that I'll need SPI since Circuit Python recommends its installation. I'm still sorta hoping to find / hear some kind of authoritative information like "raspberry pi can't do a sound card and SPI" or "they can, but your setup won't work, do ___".

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have either of these products but perhaps they both use the same set of pins on the SPI bus.

Bonnet needs 18,19,21 while I think neopixel uses 18 as standard. The neopixel document says pin can be changed.

Comment: You're right, for this reason I've been using pin 12. A part of the issue here is that it was working fine for a while. No conflict of pins, just suddenly, after a few reboots, it lost the soundcards until I nixed the SPI stuff.

Comment: Are you saying that at some point you had both the bonnet and neopixel working at the same time?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being unclear, I've updated the question (quite a bit) to make it more clear that the lights and sound were working ok, past more than 1 reboot, before they disappeared. If you click on the docs I linked to you can see that the neopixels can use a few different GPIOs and the speakers consume a few. I used one where they don't overlap for this reason.